# Joining a Bag of Tuples into a Single String without any Custom Pig UDFs

Tags: apache-pig

How do I concatenate a bag of tuples (ex: {(664),(823),(8),(47),(35),(27),(13),(16),(4),(8),(6)}) into a single string with Pig Latin that does not rely on writing a custom UDF?

Answer (score 3):

this is an example for a UDF concatenating strings which are tuples in a bag assuming there is 1 item in each tuple (string delimiter in the output will be an '_'):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

@outputSchema("schema:chararray")
def convertBagToStr(acctBag):
    return "_".join([str(i[0]) for i in sorted(acctBag)])
```

in the Pig script :

```
register '$udf_dir/myUDF.py' using jython as funcs;

a = foreach mygroup generate funcs.convertBagToStr(mybag) as bag_str;
```

Comment: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#bagtostring
Flatten a bag into a string. This UDF will use the character '_' as the default delimiter if one is not provided. Example: bag = {(a),(b),(c)} BagToString(bag) -> 'a_b_c' BagToString(bag, '+') -> 'a+b+c' bag = {(a,b), (c,d), (e,f)} BagToString(bag) --> 'a_b_c_d_e_f' If input bag is null, this UTF will return null;

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this in just Pig Latin. According to [Programming Pig](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/data_model.html), bags are unordered collections of tuples. Thus, trying to concatenate them gives an ambiguous result unless you were able to specify an ordering—which is possible through a custom UDF.